# How do I center an object in java

Tags: java, swing, button, field, center

I want to make a simple program that will have one button and multiple fields. When I was planning this out in my head I wanted to use a gridlayout, or at least cent the button at first since I am learning. Here is what I have so far, my question that I am leading to is where do I put in my grid layout, or do I set the alignment center in the panel, frame or button?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Normal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        JButton button = new JButton("why");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField field= new JTextField();


    //button
    button.setSize(50, 50);

    //Field
    field.setSize(250, 25);

    //Frame
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.add(button);

        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use setSize, let the layout manager take care of it. Try using a different layout manager. GridLayout will make the components fill the available space equally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always add the components in a `Container` of the `JFrame`. Set the Layout of `Container` as `GridLayout`. For example You can change your code as follows:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Normal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        JButton button = new JButton("why");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField field= new JTextField();
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));//Devides the container in 3 rows and 1 column
        c.add(panel);//Add in first row
        c.add(button);//Add in second row
        c.add(field);//Add in third row
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

Comment: adding the component directly to the frame is equivalent to adding them to the ContentPane.

Comment: @user1241388: My Pleasure.:) . And If it solved your problem then mark the answer as accepted. Look at here to know how to accept the answer..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

In an approach where you extend your class from JFrame, you could simply set where you would like to add the components. If you have a panel with ex. a button, you could add it like this:

```
add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Hope this helps.